# Doing a SQL Query with inserted/fetched object parameters giving error

Tags: php, sql, class, object

I'm trying to use OO Php which is a new thing for me (well, Php is too).  The following line is having an error:

class.OLAPdatabase.php:

```
switch($color){
    case "2":  //this is first case
    $sqlQry = "UPDATE VisEData SET ParameterValue = '" . $tempObj->Yevaluation . "' where MeasurementID = '" . $tempObj->parameterDesc . "' and TestUnitID = '" . $tempObj->parameterID . "' and ColorID = '" . $color . "'";
    break;
...
```

The class being referred to looks like this:

class.ViseParameter.php:

```
class ViseParameter  
{  
   var $parameterID = null;
   var $parameterDesc = null;
   var $Yevaluation = null;
   var $Mevaluation = null;
   var $Cevaluation = null;
   var $Kevaluation = null;
   var $Comments = null;

   //**********************************************************
   //                  -[ F_u_n_c_t_i_o_n_s ]-
   //**********************************************************
   function __construct() 
   {}  // END - Constructor
   //**********************************************************
   function __destruct() 
   {}
```

The error message for the UPDATE line is:

```
error updating VisEData with case 2Error in statement preparation/execution. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22018 [SQLSTATE] => 22018 [1] => 245 [code] => 245 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PR Spots Marks' to data type int. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PR Spots Marks' to data type int. ))
```

I already know that the data in the ViseParameter class is fine. **I know my update statement works fine if I put a string variable into the spots where I have $tempObj->Yevaluation type of thing, but this is the first time using data from the class to do the update.**  For example, the update worked fine when it was:

```
$sqlQry = "UPDATE VisEData SET ParameterValue = '" . $Yevaluation . "' where MeasurementID = '" . $MCBands . "' and TestUnitID = '" . $TestUnitID . "' and ColorID = '" . $YColor . "'";
```

I'm not seeing much supporting info in a web search, but this isn't a simple problem.

This is using MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Exactly as the message says: `... when converting the varchar value 'PR Spots Marks' to data type int.`. Since you don't explain anything about your query we can't really help you. This has nothing to do with OOP, and you'd get the exact same message if you were constructing your query string using conventional functional programming methods.

Comment: It's not the same thing, Not sure how you mapped `$Parametervalue` onto `$TestUnitID` your issue is that the variables aren't what you think they are, try echoing them or debugging

Comment: Thanks guys!  You are both correct.  I was referring to the wrong ParameterValue object value for MeasurementID, and my TestUnitID wasn't stored in the object but I was mistakingly using an object parameter for that.  I wish I had another set of eyes to run things by over here.  Thanks for your help for ideas of what to look into.